# jQuery - slide will open but doesn't close

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery code that when a user clicks on the `<h2>` title it opens a `div` with its content inside.

**Html code:**

```
<div class="content1">
    <h2 class="vertical"> open text box</h2>
</div>
<div class="content1-text" >
        Text box
   <div id="back1" style="float:right;">HOME</div>
</div>
```

**Css code:**

```
.content1-text {
   padding: 20px;
   width: 920px;
   min-height: 560px;
   height: auto;
   background: #61752d;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$('.content1').click(function () {
    if($('.content1').is(':visible')){
            $('.content1-text').toggle('slide', {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 1000);
    }
    else{
        $('#back1').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000, function(){ $('#content1-text').fadeIn();});
    }
});
```

The problem now is, that when a user clicks on **open text box** it opens the box, but when the user clicks on **HOME** it doesn't slide back as it was in the beginning...

Im trying to get it slide from left to right.. and when it closes from right to left.

I tried to find it on the web but with out any luck.

My JsFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/PBm88/)**

Comment: I don't think you know what you're telling it to do...

Comment: I know that when i click on something with a class name content1 that it will open something (in my case my div) with the classname content1-text. with a slide and a duration of 1 second.. but the closing is where i get my struggles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you really need to review the toogle method http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You can do sometihng like this:

```
$('.content1').click(function () {
    $('.content1-text').toggle("slow");
});
$('#back1').click(function () {
    $('.content1-text').toggle("slow");
});
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/PBm88/11/**

**EDIT**

After more details of the expected result you can do a function based on the `classname` that enables the slide animation for the relative container:

```
$('.vertical').click(function () {
  var id=$(this).parent().attr('class'),
      slid='.'+id+'-text';
  $(slid).show().animate({
      width:'920px',
      opacity: '1'
  },2000)
});
$('.back').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({
      width:'0px',
      opacity: '0'
    }, 
    {duration:2000,
     complete: function() {
         $( this ).hide();
        }
     });
});
```

New Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/PBm88/59/**

Comment: That's the way just keep the classes `content` and `back` in all divs i use `next` and `parent` for that reason. Can you add a fiddle with multiple containers?

Comment: Yes thats it! i only changed the duration from 2000 to 1000. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PBm88/13/

Use this jQuery instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button, #back1').click(function() {
            $('#box').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });
```

The CSS:

```
.visible { display: block; }
```

Also modified the HTML with three ID's.

Do any animation in CSS.  Modify as you see fit.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP expects it to do.

Comment: This is indeed not what i need. It still doesn't close when the user clicks on home. (all the right of the div)

Comment: I apologize, I didn't see the home button part in the jsfiddle it was cut off on the right side.

I've modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a click handler for the home button

Try

```
$('.content1').click(function () {
        $('.content1-text').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000);
});

$('#back1').click(function(){
        $('.content1-text').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RxxXu/)

Comment: I think the OP wants the content to fade in/out as well

Comment: @Zeaklous well this looks more like it. But im trying it on a way that i can use it for 5 more contents. Like `.content1`, `.content2` etc..